# My laptop's cpu runs at more than 150% maximum frequency

Tags: cpu, bsod, clockspeed

I recently noticed that my CPU is running at higher than it's base clock speed.
Processor : Intel i5-8300H (2.30 GHz)

I used to get many Blue Screen (BSoD) errors when I play games like FIFA or even when I use any video converter software and any other heavy application. I have tried many fixes: chkdsk, sfc, DISM restore health but they didn't work for me. I have been using my laptop for 2 years and it has been able to handle heavy application quite well. I don't understand if my CPU running at higher speeds is related to this or not.

Here is a screenshot of my Resource Manager: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBPxQ.jpg

It reaches 170-180% when I use something heavy. Is it normal?

EDIT: My Laptop has also started heating up a lot recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's completely normal.

Let's [have a look at the spec sheet](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134876/intel-core-i5-8300h-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html).

```
Processor Base Frequency 2.30 GHz
Max Turbo Frequency 4.00 GHz
```

What Resource Monitor reports as "Maximum Frequency" is just the CPU's "base frequency", which is the frequency specced to fit within TDP. You CPU has a TDP of 45 W. That means if your laptop's cooling solution is capable of dissipating 45 W of heat, your CPU should be able to maintain 2.30 GHz indefinitely.

*Turbo* is a concept introduced in the last decade, where the CPU can run at higher frequencies for short bursts. For example, your CPU has a max turbo frequency of 4.00 GHz for as long as it remains at a low enough temperature. If your laptop can only cool 45 W, and running at 4.00 GHz generates,say, 80 W (made up number) - after a few seconds, the CPU will get too hot and will drop back down to its base of 2.30 GHz.

This is good since many tasks are bursty in nature - e.g. when you're browsing the web, you'll have a short burst to load a page, and then minutes of idling where the CPU can cool back down, ready to burst again.

It's not so great for extended usage, such as playing a game.

Now, if your cooling solution is overspecced, as is common on desktops, then the CPU may be able to maintain some level of boost indefinitely. If your CPU has a TDP of 45 W, but your cooling solution can dissipate 60 W, then it might be able to boost to, say, 3.00 GHz indefinitely - but any higher, and it will need to drop back down to cool off.

---

Now that we have the turbo boost discussion out of the way, we can look at why your laptop may be slowing down over time. Most commonly, this is because of overheating. Laptop cooling solutions operate within tight boundaries, and just a little change can throw the whole thing off.

- A common issue is dust. When dust clogs the heatsink, it drastically reduces the cooling capacity of the laptop. Over two years, the blockage can become quite severe. If you are comfortable opening your laptop up, you should do so, and clear any dust from the heatsink and fan. Depending on design, there may even be solid balls of dust stuck behind the fan shroud.
- Sometimes, the thermal compound between the CPU and heatsink can deteriorate over time. Replacing it with fresh compound can improve cooling. This is a rather more complex operation than just cleaning the heatsink, so you should only do it if you are comfortable - or ask a more tech savvy friend, or take it to a PC repair shop.

Comment: Thank you! And about the heating issue - In addition to removing the dust, If I buy a cooling pad for my laptop, will it help?

Comment: @DhyeyDoshi It can help, but you won't see nearly as much improvement as you would with removing dust and repasting. The hardest part is getting the heat out of the laptop in the first place.